# How can I create 10-character, unique codes with no collisions, but without being predictable?

Tags: algorithms, hash

If we are using numbers and letters, there are $36^{10}$ unique combinations. Collision is already unlikely, but I need it to be impossible, so using hashing is out of the picture(?).

The use-case is users redeeming each one if they have been "activated" as redeemable. Think like Webkinz codes.

An inefficient solution would be to generate all of them at once, have a property on each saying whether it has been activated or not and keep a pool of those that have been redeemed and those that haven't.

Keeping a database of $36^{10}$ codes just because I can't come up with a clever algorithm is pissing me off, so I'm here for your help.

Any ideas?

Comment: See [rfc4122](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122) for UUID's

Comment: @kelalaka Unless I missed something, those seem to be basically "hash and hope". The spec is only that the UUIDs are unique with high probability.

Comment: @DavidRicherby [version 3 and 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Versions) use hash so they can have a collision. This one uses the MAC address to solve this issue.

Comment: How unpredictable do they have to be? For example, is it enough to use, say, seven characters to implement a counter, with three digits as a checksum? Start at some random-looking value, and increment the counter each time by something co-prime to 36. Possibly apply some fixed permutation to the output so the first few digits aren't always the same. That's certainly breakable, but much better than 0000000001, 0000000002, ...

Comment: Use the solution that pisses you off. It works, and the developer who has to maintain it in the future will understand it. That developer might be you. You need persistent storage anyway to keep track of redeemed codes, no matter how you do it.

Answer (score 1):

$36^{10}$ is approximately 52-bit. Now;

- Generate a secret key $k$ for AES-128
- Encrypt the rowID with $\text{unique_code} = \operatorname{AES}_k(rowID)$, and assuming that the key never changes.

Since AES with a key selects permutation for all possible permutations from $2^{\ell}$ to $2^{\ell}$, where $\ell$ with a key, then by fixing a key, you fixed a **secret permutation**. Therefore the output is distinct for every distinct input. It is **unpredictable** since AES is assumed to be secure against Known-Plaintext Attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a process to hand out unique codes, without requiring any storage or memory:

Step 1.  Use [format-preserving encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) to define a block cipher that maps an integer from $\{0,1,\dots,36^{10}-1\}$ to an integer from $\{0,1,\dots,36^{10}-1\}$.

Step 2. Pick a secret key for this block cipher.

Step 3. The $i$th code you hand out will be the encryption of $i$ under your secret key.  Now you only need to store a counter with the largest value of $i$ you have used so far.

To keep track of which codes have been redeemed, you need storage proportional to the number of codes redeemed.  So, store a list of codes that were previously redeemed, or use a bitmap, or use any other data structure.  There's no way to avoid that much storage.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bitmap. Map the values to some sort of numerical order and then use that number as a map the proper bit. The first int (assuming 32-bit and unsigned) would store values 0-4,294,967,295 the second int would store 4,294,967,296 - ... and so on. 
Even with some overhead this should all easily fit into 10 MB and lookup/setting values is quick since you know the size beforehand and everything can be done with bit manipulation.

Once you get a code in you check if that bit has been set to 1, if not then its valid and you set that bit to 1.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, here. What does "use that number as a map the proper bit" mean? What do you mean by storing four billion values in a 32-bit int? A 32-bit int can either store one value in the range zero to four billion, or 32 individual bits. It can't store four billion things at the same time.